# Flutter Splash screen is not changing pages

Tags: flutter, dart

//Here is my Splash Screen

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  doSomeAsyncStuff() {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);

      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => BusinessList(),
          ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/ledgerslogofinal.png',
          width: 250,
          height: 250,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

}
If the user is not null the splash screen has redirect to BusinessList() otherwise it has to redirect to LoginScreen()

Here is the error msg in my console
E/flutter (20189): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _SplashScreenState.initState() completed.
E/flutter (20189): When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
E/flutter (20189): Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.

Comment: Why you call `Navigator.pop` before you call `Navigator.push`? If you want to remove `SplashScreen` from navigation stack try using `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil`

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of poping and pushing routes inside the initState you should rather toggle wich screen your returning :

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return user == null ? LoginScreen() : BusinessList();
  }
}
```

So if your user is not logged in (i.e. user == null) you return your LoginScreen, else you return your main screen.

Comment: i have tried your code its working but in splash screen i want to show some image

Comment: the code which you provided is giving blank page before redirecting

Comment: i Want to avoid that blank page instead need to show some images

Comment: @Vishali Then you must provide an image to display in the AndroidManifest.xml. I guess the blank screen you see is the transition between the launch of the app and the start of flutter. This could help you : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen

Comment: Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
        // user not logged ==> Login Screen
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen()), (route) => false);
      } else {
        // user already logged in ==> Home Screen
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => BusinessList()),
            (route) => false);
      }
    });

Comment: now working with the above changes

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable time

Comment: But isn't it better to instantiate your splash screen as what it is (splash screen + launch screen for Android only) ? So it will be displayed when the app start, and you don't have to wait this extra second (which you use to show your logo) and it will be smoother I guess, less code (get rid of that timer) and you won't have a black screen while Android and iOS launch try app.

Comment: ok i will remove and try